# How to send app data securely to a recipient/server

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I'm currently developing an android app where the user has to fill out and successfully send the data of a few text fields to a recipient/server, to enable a feature.

The big issue is how to do that in a secure way to be protected against e.g. decompiling. My concern is not the security during the transport but rather the security of the transport medium.

What I've thought/read so far:

1. I could send the data via mail with the Java Mail API. 
   First of all, I don't want require that the user has to enter his mail credentials and SMTP server.
   That would mean that I have to include the credentials to a mail account in the app, though.
   To avoid the situation that somebody decompiles the app and takes over my mail account, I thought of encrypting methods, but even if I would save the aes encrypted version of the password, the attacker could decompile the app and could add a syso to output the decrypted password.
   The same applies to OAuth authentication because I have to store an authentication token.
   In addition to the mail version, I read something about getting the password with a POST request from a web service, which doesn't seem safer at all.

   I could search for free smtp server without the need of credentials, but I want something I can rely on instead of waking up each day and looking if the service still works.
2. Send the data to a web service.
   Okay that would require more work for me, but I would accept that, if there would be a solution without saving the credentials in the app or having a web service which accepts data from everybody.

Have I overlooked something? Or is there no safe method without asking the user for his mail credentials or google account etc. ?

Comment: Perhaps you should check out www.parse.com (if you haven't already)

Comment: Before sending - connect to the server (handshake), send the public key to the client, send the encrypted message to the server, decrypt with the private key.

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm not concerned about security during the transport. And in your solution everybody could flood my web service with false data.

Answer (score 0):

1. OAuth would probably work. The nice thing about OAuth is that if a token is compromised it can be revoked on the server side.
2. You could create a web service that accepts TCP connections on some port. You could have some authentication mechanism for example Digest authentication that would be carried out before accepting data.

Another option would be to use an API such as [Golgi](http://www.golgi.io). Golgi requires a developer key, app key and app instance id to connect to the servers and send data. In the event these credentials somehow get compromised you can simply change the app key and push a new version of the app through the Play Store.